# PHP foreach: replace value in nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to change 'value2' to 'My string'. I know this is possible by using the array keys but I wonder if it's a cleaner way.

```
$nested_array[] = array('value1', 'value2', 'value3');

foreach($nested_array as $values){

    foreach($values as $value){

        if($value == 'value2'){
            $value = 'My string';
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the reference operator `&`to pass values by reference:

```
foreach($nested_array as &$values) {
    foreach($values as &$value) {
        do_something($value);
    }
}
unset($values); // These two lines are completely optional, especially when using the loop inside a
unset($value);  // small/closed function, but this avoids accidently modifying elements later on.
```

Comment: While this might work for the given example, you should keep in mind, that it is a bad idea to modify the array, over which you are iterating. Especially when you add/remove items.

Comment: You should not forget to `unset($value)` after the loop – otherwise accessing that variable afterwards in your code might have unexpected side effects.

Comment: As long as you only modify values you're pretty much save. Changing the array itself is something different, but that's something you have to consider no matter which kind of loop you're using.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed. Setting `$values = '';` under the foreach-loop clears the array. Do I have to unset both `$values` and `$value`?

Comment: If you want to be 100% safe, yes, added those two lines to the example.

Comment: And I have to add the `&` before both `$values` and `$value` even though it's only `$value` I want to change?

Comment: If you're not using the `&`, you'll create a copy of the element for the loop, so you won't be modifying the original array.

Comment: It's the pink warning in [foreach manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), but if you're not going to use the $values and $value variables in the script anymore (especially within a custom function), you don't need unsets. But agree, it's safer to unset them.

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear. I meant if i have to set add the `&` before both variables or if it's possible to only add it before the `$value` variable. Though your comment suggest this isn't possible?

Comment: Yes, I understood you, you'll need it in both cases, because otherwise you'll create a copy again (at least on that level), so you won't modiy the original value.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) for this:

```
array_walk_recursive($nested_array,
                     function(&$v) {
                         if ($v == 'value2') $v = 'My string';
                     }
);
```

This would work for any level of nesting and you don't need to remember to `unset` anything afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
function strReplaceAssoc(array $replace, $subject) { 
   return str_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $subject);    
}

$nested_array[] = array('value1', 'value2', 'value3');

foreach($nested_array as $values){

    foreach($values as $value){

        $replace = array( 
            'value2' => 'My string' 
            );

        $new_values = strReplaceAssoc($replace,$value);

       echo $new_values . '<br />';

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function array_search is what you 're searching for.

```
$key = array_search('value2', $nested_array);
$nested_array[$key] = 'My String';
```

This solution would be more performant than iterating through the whole array.

Comment: doesn't help for nested arrays, as you would need to add some kind of recursion to support infinite depth. Your example will fail, because $nested_array contains an array of values - not the values.

Comment: Okay ... for nested arrays you could use the RecursiveArrayIterator object of the SPL deliverd with php. Look for the second user comment at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php. This should solve your problem on a very smart way.

Answer (score 0):

By using array keys:

```
$nested_array = array();
$nested_array[] = array('value1', 'value2', 'value3');

foreach($nested_array as $key => $values){

    foreach($values as $key2 => $value){

        if($value == 'value2'){
            $nested_array[$key][$key2] = 'My string';
        }
    }
}
var_export($nested_array);
// array ( 0 => array ( 0 => 'value1', 1 => 'My string', 2 => 'value3', ), )
```